# how to delete data from contact table and list table

Tags: sql, sql-server

in sql server management 2014 there are a main table ,name Contact and another name ContactPhoto and also there is a contact table between them name ContactAndContactPhoto. the relationship between them is same. first a contact will be inserted second a list of photos will be inserted in ContactPhoto at the same time for that contactId in ContactAndContactPhoto, PhotoId will be inserted.

the problem is when I want to delete a contact I need to delete its information too.i should pass a contactId and delete related row in  Contact , ContactAndContactPhoto  and ContactPhoto that was simple in first two table but for ContactPhoto i need to obtain PhotoId list for that ContactId ...for this i declare a list :

```
    Declare @MyList int
    Set @MyList = (Select PhotoId From tblContactAndtblContactPhoto Where 
   ContactId=@Id);



 Delete tblContactPhoto Where Id IN(@MyList)
```

or some other way to get a list of PhotoId but reached to errors like:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

would you please help me to understand what should i do to first clear all photos related to that contact and then delete related data in two other table

thanks

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: thanks and excuse me it was my first time

Comment: Firstly dynamic procedures to delete rows if you are not familiar with doing so can go badly wrong so please practice on on test data.

Are you familiar with with concepts of JOIN or CASCADE DELETE because I suspect this is what you want to do here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query statement.Your sub query statement returns multiple rows.

```
Declare @MyList table
(
    PhotoId INT
)

DECLARE @Id INT
INSERT INTO @MyList
Select PhotoId From tblContactAndtblContactPhoto  Where  ContactId=@Id;

DELETE From tblContactAndtblContactPhoto  Where  ContactId=@Id;
Delete tblContactPhoto Where Id IN(SELECT PhotoId FROM @MyList)
```

Comment: thanks but there is new error: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_tblContactAndtblContactPhoto_tblContactPhoto". The conflict occurred in database "Padra.PhoneBook", table "dbo.tblContactAndtblContactPhoto", column 'PhotoId'.

Comment: @zahra92112, in this case, you need to delete data from `dbo.tblContactAndtblContactPhoto` beacause PhotoId is the foreign key of this table `dbo.tblContactAndtblContactPhoto`.

Comment: I do this.first delete data from dbo.tblContactAndtblContactPhoto and then delete from tblContactPhoto but the result was that the data just delete from dbo.tblContactAndtblContactPhoto .nothing happend to tblContactPhoto

Comment: @zahra92112, I have updated query, Please check and let me know if you will face further problem. Thanks.

Comment: sorry but there is still the same problem: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_tblContactAndtblContactPhoto_tblContactPhoto". The conflict occurred in database "Padra.PhoneBook", table "dbo.tblContactAndtblContactPhoto", column 'PhotoId'.